# How to load in-memory pdf to TWebBrowser on Delphi Seattle?

Tags: delphi, pdf, twebbrowser

I'm searching for method to show in-memory pdf without saving it to file in TWebBrowser component. I've found interesting example at http://www.jasontpenny.com/blog/2010/03/23/custom-protocol-handler-in-delphi/ but it does not work for pdf ( i have used mime type application/pdf). Can someone to help me find solution?

Comment: This is pretty vague. There are a number of different `TWebBrowser` components. VCL or FMX? Desktop or mobile? Beyond that, there are different ways for PDFs to be shown. Which do you want?

Comment: I use desktop Win32 VCL version. Please, suggest at least one way. Thank you

Comment: There are many ways. If you use a modern OS, and configure the web browser control to render using latest browser, then PDF rendering is built in. Otherwise it's liable to be done via a plugin. But you likely have no control over the other user's machines. Or do you only want to do this on a machine that you control? More broadly, I'd ask you how well you understand the process by which browsers render PDF?

Comment: Now i don't understand how it renders pdf.I need show pdf on local computer, prefer by plugable protocol.

Comment: And you only need this for one computer, your own?

Comment: Yes, only my own computer

Comment: Please, suggest at least one way

Comment: Not until you decide how you want it to be rendered.